# Hint is not showing in Edit text in lower api

Tags: android, android-edittext, device

EditText is not showing hint with the following XML code, it is working in some devices like mine is API 19, but not showing hint in android 2.3.3

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/street1ET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/street1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />
```

Comment: I think the API level doesn't match with the android version you are using :/

Comment: try removing background and textappearnce one by one, i don't know it will help or not but try once.

Comment: I think the issue is in your backgroung dawable image. Please remove and try.

Comment: it is working in the api 19, so i think background image is not a problem @Sadiq

Comment: Then may be your hint color match to your default device background. Try to change the hint color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a single line and it will work, i.e `android:ellipsize="start"`

Also try to change `hint` color of `EditText` like  this: `android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"` or relevant color code.

Comment: thanks Himanshu, it worked only with the ellipsize property for the text field, color is ok

Answer (score 0):

Put below one line in EditText

```
android:textColorHint="@color/your_custom_color"
```

Enjoy!!!